# How can I call a new web page from javascript / jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a button like this:

```
<button id="CreateButton" title="Create Task">Create Task</button>
```

I wrote code to capture the click event:

```
        $('#CreateButton').click(function (event) {
           event.preventDefault
           var datastore = $("#SelectedDatastore").val();
           xxxxxx
        });
```

But I want make the clicking call an action method on my MVC controller with some parameters. For example the paramater and value of datastore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to go to another page, you could change the location:

```
window.location = "MyPage.aspx?paramater=MyParamValue";
```

Or if you don't want to change the current page, but just to execute an action, use [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

```
$.get("MyPage.aspx", { paramater: "MyParamValue" }, function(data) {
  alert("Response from the server: " + data);
});
```

Comment: How can I pass parameters also?

Comment: Hello Oleg. What I need to do is call an MVC action and then that would change the current page. I think what you suggest as the first solution would do that best?

Comment: Yes, if you want to change the current page, than the first solution is for you.

Answer (score 0):

[XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) is the standard solution here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to actually change the page that is loaded in the browser, you would need to set the `window.location` attribute to the URL of the new page you want to visit.  This will cause the browser to browse to that page as if the user had typed it in the address bar.

Comment: thanks. I updated my question now. How could I also pass parameters? I guess this is some kind of javascript call?

Comment: You can take a look at Oleg's answer to find this out

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a `Create` operation, it should not be done with a `GET` request, like changing `window.location`. Instead you have to do it with `POST` Request. Check this code:

```
$('#CreateButton').click(function (event) {
    var theUrl = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/SomethingControlloer/Create")%>';

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: theUrl,  
        data: { },   // Data to send with request
        dataType: "json",
        success: function () {},
        failure: function () { alert("Error!"); }
    });
});
```

Of course, for `ResolveUrl` to work, you should already have a registered MVC route in `Global.asax.cs`, and your action method should have `[HttpPost]` attribute.