# Calling my web page from jQuery

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I call a new web page from javascript / jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476637/how-can-i-call-a-new-web-page-from-javascript-jquery)

I just asked a question about how to do this and had some suggestions. Here's the code that I came up with:

```
$('#CreateButton').click(function (event) {
 event.preventDefault
 var datastore = $("#SelectedDatastore").val();
 var answer = $("#SelectedAnswer").val();
 window.location = "/adminTasks/Create?datastore=" + datastore + "&selectedAnswer=" + answer;
});
```

Can someone confirm this is okay and there's no optimization needed.

Is there any difference if I use `document.location.href` ?

Comment: If you did get some answers you should be posting it on that post itself - creating a new thread breaks up the link and what exactly to look for. I suggest you post the response on the same thread.

Comment: Well I accepted the answer for the last thread and wanted to give another person a chance to have a follow up accepted.

Comment: Agreed :) It's only lack of context. Someone needs to find your old post to know what it is that you were looking for to ascertain whether optimization is indeed required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All looks good apart from it should be `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: Thanks. I will change. I also have many other event.prefentDefault I need to change. Thanks for telling me.